# Extract text from web page

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, extract

Need help with extracting some text from a web page using beautifulsoup.
For me its to difficult to figure out how to write the code so I would be very thankful if someone would help me with this.

On https://www.smhi.se/vadret/vadret-i-sverige/meteorologens-kommentar#ws=wpt-a,proxy=wpt-a,area=3
I would like to extract the text in the box that is named "Prognos för Nordvästra Götaland" to a text file.
I will be running this on my raspberry pi.
Is there a "simple" beautifulsoup script to get this done?
I got a basic script when i installed bs4, looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
print "Opening site..."

f = requests.get('https://www.smhi.se/vadret/vadret-i-sverige/meteorologens-kommentar#ws=wpt-a,proxy=wpt-a,area=3')

soup = BeautifulSoup(f.text,'lxml')

print soup
```

This prints the content of the html page.

Answer (score 0):

The data you see on the page is loaded dynamically via JavaScript (so BeautifulSoup won't help you here). But you can simulate Ajax request with `requests` module:

```
import json
import requests

data_url = 'https://www.smhi.se/wpt-a/backend_metcomments/frodo/oversikt_text'

data = requests.get(data_url).json()
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4)) # <-- uncomment this to see all data

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    print(data['districts']['NORDVÄSTRA GÖTALAND']['header'], file=f_out)
    print(data['districts']['NORDVÄSTRA GÖTALAND']['text'], file=f_out)
```

This will produce file `output.txt` with content:

```
Mycket milt och en smula blåsigt
Mycket moln, sent i kväll och under inledningen av natten passerande regn. I morgon lördag skurar och 5-8 grader. Sydvästlig vind, efterhand med friska vindbyar.
```

Comment: Great! But running this as a python script (smhi.py) generates an error: File "smhi.py", line 10
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file smhi.py on line 10, but no encoding declared. So I tried to add # coding=utf-8 at the top of the file but it didn't help. What could I be doing wrong? Is it not right to run it like a python script?

Comment: @MicaelFredriksson Make sure you save the file with utf-8 encoding, also use Python 3 instead Python 2.

Comment: @AndrejKesley Checked and it was saved as utf-8. Used python 3 and that worked! One final question, how do I get the last line in that box that says when the text was updated? (Senast uppdaterad: idag klockan 20:50)

Comment: @MicaelFredriksson The last line is generated automatically with Javascript. But when you uncomment the line with data, you will see there are keys `"updated"` and `"updatedUTC"` - like `"updated": "2020-01-31T20:50:41Z"`, so that's your time when the file was updated.

Comment: @AndrejKesley so I can't get that time to show up as a line in the output.txt?

Comment: @MicaelFredriksson Yes you can, but you need format the string with date first.

Comment: @AndrejKesley been trying to get the update time to be written in the txt file but once again I can't figure it out...Can you please explain how I should write this so I get the time thats on the last line? And I mean the time that is written at the web page where the other text are taken from, not when my file is updated. Hope you see what I mean.

Comment: @MicaelFredriksson The time and date is in variable `data['updated']`. Look at [`strptime()` and `strftime()` functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) how to format the date to desired string. You can search Stack Overflow, surely there's many questions/answers how to do it.

Comment: @AndrejKesley Ok, I'll take a look at that and see if I manage to solve it. Thanks för the help.